# Confusion over relationship in a tennis tournament context

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship

I'm making a simple tennis database that features:

- Tournaments (Mens/womens singles, Mens/womens doubles, Mixed doubles)
- Players
- Results

My Results table looked something like

- ResultID
- DatePlayed
- Player1ID (became ParticipantID1)
- Player1Score
- Player2ID (became ParticipantID2)
- Player2Score

I then realised that a player could play in more than one tournament so I needed another table, Participant (or could be called team, or couple).

- ParticipantID
- PlayerID
- TournamentID

With all three ID's being composite.

Now Joe (ID: 1) and Tom (ID: 2) can be a doubles partner but Joe can still play in the Singles

Participant ID -- PlayerID -- TournamentID

1 ----------------- 1 ------------ 1

1 ----------------- 2 ------------ 1

2 ----------------- 1 ------------ 2

Now the problem I have with this is that auto-increment/identify would have to be turned for the Participant table meaning more coding work would have to be done (when creating and validating etc).

The second problem I have with this is that all the singles players data would be repeating, as they would be stored in the Player table and also the Participant table.

I could have another Results table, i.e. DoubleResults, but I feel this isn't necessary.

Is this the only way it can be done or has my mind just gone blank?

Comment: Why would singles player data be repeated?  Should just be the PlayerID that gets used multiple times.

Comment: Because really the Results table should only link to a PlayerID or a ParticipantID. I guess a -If TournamentType = 'Singles' Use PlayerID Else Use ParticipantID- logic could be used but it doesn't seem great?

Answer (score 0):

A tournament will have many matches.  Therefore you need a one to many relationship between tournaments and matches.

A match will have a type (singles, doubles, etc).  So your match table has to include a type id.

You will need a many to many relationship between teams and matches.  A team can have either one or two players, depending on the type of match. At this point, it comes down to how much detail you want to store.  It might be simply good enough to store the winning team id in this table.